# Open System Preferences with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos

I set up a shortcut in System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts:

[image]

But it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Not a "shortcut", but one option with maybe a few keystrokes: **Cmd** + **Space** + **S**, to open Spotlight and start typing *System Preferences*.  Then **Enter**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add it as a global shortcut (under *All Applications*, not *System Preferences*), and include an ellipsis in the menu name (either `...` or `…`.):

[image]

The only apps this method works for are System Preferences, System Information, and App Store. For others, see:

- [Launch an OS X app with a keyboard shortcut - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/266829/launch-an-os-x-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/309144#309144) (instructions for using AppleScripts, a list of third party apps that support application triggers)
- [OSX show/hide specific app global hotkey? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/339493/osx-show-hide-specific-app-global-hotkey/339709#339709) (instructions for using Automator services)

Comment: Note that for any particular menu item that appears with three trailing dots, exactly one of either `...` or `…` is correct, and the other will not work.

Comment: @Daniel Are you sure, and based on what? I've found that `...` can be always substituted for `…` and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not *sure*, but it *is* the result of my experimentation. Just to reconfirm, after you posted 26 minutes ago, I tried creating a keyboard shortcut for `System Preferences…` and it doesn't launch System Preferences, but `System Preferences...` does.

Answer (score 4):

When you add a keyboard shortcut and list it for a particular application, the key binding only applies when that application is active. Thus, if you made Control-Shift-Z a shortcut for Zoom and applied that to Safari, that would mean that in Safari, and only in Safari, pressing Control-Shift-Z would zoom (i.e. same as clicking the the green button in the upper left hand corner of the window). Binding keyboard shortcuts to particular applications usually makes sense because each application has its own set of menu commands.

In your particular case, creating a key binding to launch System Preferences and binding it to System Preferences is guaranteed to never do what you want, because the only time it would launch System Preferences would be when System Preferences is already the active application.

The fix is to insert `System Preferences...` (with three periods, not an ellipse) as a shortcut in the All Applications section.

[image]

Comment: Why does adding "..." makes it work?

Comment: The text in the "Menu Title" box has to exactly match the text of the menu item you want to select. In the case of the "System Preferences..." menu item, the menu text isn't "System Preferences"; it's "System Preferences...".

Comment: got it, didn't realize that you were talking about application shortcuts as opposed to a service to be used as a global shortcut.  Thank you.