# Open System Settings with a shortcut

Tags: macos, shortcut, system-settings

I'd like to open System Settings (formerly System Preferences) with a global keyboard shortcut. How do I do that in macOS Sonoma 14+?

---

*Related [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/26513/6902) is outdated.*

Answer (score 0):

You want to get to *Keyboard shortcuts*. Open *System Settings* itself, and then:

1. Search for "key"
2. Click *Keyboard shortcuts*

[image]

In *Keyboard shortcuts*, you want to click ***App Shortcuts > All Applications > +***

[image]

Finally, For *Menu title* enter "System Settings...". Click the white area for  *Keyboard shortcut*, and then type your shortcut (e.g. type alt-cmd-comma at the same time).

[image]